# How can I change product image according to select diffrent attribute sets in Magento configuable product?

Tags: php, magento, configurable-product

I am working on Magento 1.9 and I have added attribute set and create a configurable product and have different associated products now I need to change product image according select different size and color

Answer (score 4):

GO to :  System=>Configuration => Configurable Swatches =>Select 'Product Attributes to Color and Size and Save.

https://prnt.sc/fhpapg

Answer (score 2):

Its Magento's default feature. You just need to convert your options in swatch. Check below reference site in which explain how to convert options in swatches.

http://www.magetraining.com/us/blog/how-to-set-up-configurable-swatches-in-magento-versions-1-9-x/

Answer (score 0):

Use This Extension.

> https://amasty.com/color-swatches-pro.html

or you can also use Magento's default feature in Configuration(Configurable Swatches).